# Preventing Arm Neon d8-d15 spilling in a function

Tags: assembly, clang++, arm64, calling-convention, neon

I'm having a function to be called through function pointer, which uses all the 32 Arm Neon registers.

The calling convention requires to spill and restore the bottom part of the registers d8-d15, however, I like to get rid of that for instance by delegating the burden to the higher level function.

Example:

```
#include "arm_neon.h"

inline void add(float32x4x4_t &a, float32x4x4_t b) {
    a.val[0] = vaddq_f32(a.val[0], b.val[0]);
    a.val[1] = vaddq_f32(a.val[1], b.val[1]);
    a.val[2] = vaddq_f32(a.val[2], b.val[2]);
    a.val[3] = vaddq_f32(a.val[3], b.val[3]);
}

float32x4x4_t foo(float *input, int n) {
   auto a = vld4q_f32(input); input += 16;
   auto b = vld4q_f32(input); input += 16;
   auto c = vld4q_f32(input); input += 16;
   auto d = vld4q_f32(input); input += 16;
   do {
       add(a, b);
       add(b, c);
       add(c, d);
       add(d, d);
   } while (--n);
   add(a,b);
   add(a,c);
   add(a,d);
   return a;
}
...
foo(float*, int):                              // @foo(float*, int)
        stp     d11, d10, [sp, #-32]!           // 16-byte Folded Spill
        stp     d9, d8, [sp, #16]               // 16-byte Folded Spill
        mov     x9, x0
```

At least I can force the caller of the Neon intensive function to spill and restore all the callee saved registers, but is there a way to convince the non-inlined function that this has been already taken care of?

```
float32x4x4_t bar(float *input, int n) {
   foo(input, n);
   asm("" : : : "d8","d9","d10","d11","d12","d13","d14","d15");
}
...
bar(float*, int):                              // @bar(float*, int)
        stp     d15, d14, [sp, #-64]!           // 16-byte Folded Spill
        stp     d13, d12, [sp, #16]             // 16-byte Folded Spill
        stp     d11, d10, [sp, #32]             // 16-byte Folded Spill
        stp     d9, d8, [sp, #48]               // 16-byte Folded Spill
        mov     x8, x0
```

Comment: This sort of thing is usually dealt with by means of a calling convention attribute.  However, I have not found a suitable attribute for clang.

Comment: Write it directly in assembly?

Comment: Post-processing might work -- after all this is also a multiplatform application/library. I'm OTOH considering runtime code generation to reduce template specialisation explosion.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen What's your motivation for getting rid of the spilling?  Is it just the effort to write the code?  Or is there a performance motivation?  You can use an assembly macro to make the programming part easier.  Note that your spill macro is not guaranteed to work correctly.  The compiler could for example decide to save some floats in `d8` to `d15` and just move them out of the way before emitting your `asm` statement.  There is to my knowledge no fix for that, except for writing the whole wrapper in assembly.

Comment: Also note that you can reduce the length of the spilling code using a pair of `st4` instructions over 4 `stp` instructions.

Comment: The motivation is performance. It's easily less than 0.1% of all the instructions of the function -- but it will compete on the memory bandwidth on heavily multithreaded inference engine.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen The spills go on the stack, which is usually well cached.  Do you have measurements that show a significant effect on memory bandwidth?  You'll likely achieve much stronger improvements by removing the function calls alltogether, e.g. by presenting the code such that the compiler can inline most calls or, if function pointers are used, by refactoring the code such that each indirect function performs a macroscopic amount of work.

Comment: I don't have performance measurement for the spill/restore -- so far I have avoided them with inlining, but specialising convolutions with a vast number of pre- and post-processors and multiple combinations of input/output channels leads to explosion of the parameter space, which I'm going to address with function pointers (until I've got time for runtime code generation -- again across multiple platforms).
The work is at minimum something like 100 FMLA + 20-50 memory loads, where 4+4 additional loads/stores actually might matter.

Comment: The biggest limitation of course is that only 8 SIMD arguments are passed in registers -- I'd rather have the first 24, which would solve a lot of issues.